# How to route one VM traffic through another VM (Windows Hyper-V)?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, routing, hyper-v

I have the following setup that I need to run in my lab. I have one VM1 that has both external and private connections, and the other VM2 that only has private connections so VM2 cannot talk to internet now. I have set up firewall policies correctly so that VM1 and VM2 can ping each other. 
What I want to do is to let VM2 connect to internet via VM1, essentially route all incoming and outgoing traffic through VM1. Is this possible? Notice I have to do this in a windows server environment and I might need windows specific commands to do it.

Comment: You have two options, you could set up a small Linux distro to act as the router for everything, which would be the most common scenario you'd find, or you would want to set up RRAS on VM1 and configure it for routing.  This should get you started: https://technogecko.net/msft/how-to-install-and-configure-rras-routing-and-remote-access-vpn-in-windows-server-2012-and-2016/

Comment: I have already set up RRAS on VM1, but then it is not working either. Some set up is not correct over there.